# Pandas tolist() function is changing default Date time format values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime, sklearn-pandas

Consider i've a dataframe that has date value like this and it is pandas object data type.

When i apply get_date function, it's values are changed to datetime format.

[image]

When i take unique, the value remains same.

[image]

But when i take unique and convert it to list, it changes the default/original values.

[image]

.apply(get_date) function looks like this,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expected, if check [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

> **Returns**
> ndarray or ExtensionArray
> The unique values returned as a NumPy array. See Notes.

So if add `tolist` it used [`numpy.ndarray.tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) for see numpy array in native datetime format:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=3)
a = pd.DataFrame({'DATEDATACHANGED': rng.append(rng) })  
print (a)
  DATEDATACHANGED
0      2017-04-03
1      2017-04-04
2      2017-04-05
3      2017-04-03
4      2017-04-04
5      2017-04-05

print (a['DATEDATACHANGED'].unique())
['2017-04-03T00:00:00.000000000' '2017-04-04T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2017-04-05T00:00:00.000000000']

print (a['DATEDATACHANGED'].unique().tolist())
[1491177600000000000, 1491264000000000000, 1491350400000000000]
```

If want convert Series to list use [`pandas.Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print (a['DATEDATACHANGED'].tolist())
[Timestamp('2017-04-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-04-04 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2017-04-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-04-03 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2017-04-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-04-05 00:00:00')]
```

And for unique values add [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (a['DATEDATACHANGED'].drop_duplicates().tolist())
[Timestamp('2017-04-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-04-04 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2017-04-05 00:00:00')]
```

Comment: I still don't understand, why .tolist() function changes it to different values. The solution, converting first to list and dropping duplicates looks fine. My question is why it works differently for datetime, but it works fine for other data types.

Comment: @CodeRed - Because in numpy if convert datetime to list get unix format, reason why is implemented this way is more for numpy developers, you can ask [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy)